# how to write meteor migration script to insert one collection data to another collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

i need to insert one collection data to another collection. how can i write migration script for this purpose. card payments and corporate customer payment are two collections.

corporate customer payment collection has below attributes **customerID,outsTanding,date,amount,headOfficeId,insertDate**

cards payment collection has below attributes
**customerID,amount,card,packageId,cardId,classType,expireDate,headOfficeId,insertDate**

i'm inserting cards payment collection following datas to corporate customer payment collection.

> CustomerID -> card.customerID
>
> outsTanding -> card.cartId
>
> date -> card.insertDate
>
> amount -> card.amount
>
> headOfficeId ->card.headOfficeId

so how can i apply this change for old datas. how need i write meteor migration for up and down functions.
anyone who had this issue assist me.
thanks

Comment: Start by writing some code so that we can help you with that. People are not going to write your code for you :)

Comment: https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-migrations/issues/75    i used percolate:migrations package for this purpose. pls check that link i have added the answer thanks